# What information does a quantum state possess?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-states

I am currently studying quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics, and I am rather new to QM. I have a question from the following section in the notes:

> Systems of many identical particles, such as assemblies of photons or
> assemblies of electrons are very important in physics. These systems
> require a special treatment in QM because identical particles are
> indistinguishable in QM (why?). Identical quantum particles behave as
> bosons or fermions. In general, a QM particle carries a spin degree of
> freedom $\sigma$ (that can take only discrete values) in addition to
> its position degree of freedom r (that can take a continuum of
> values). Particles with semi-integer spin are fermions and obey
> Fermi-Dirac statistics while particles with integer spin are bosons
> and obey BoseEinstein statistics. Electrons (spin $1 / 2$ ) are
> fermions. Photons (spin 1 ) are bosons. The $N$-fermion wavefunction
> changes sign under an exchange of two particles, while the $N$-boson
> wavefunction remains unchanged. Let $\left|\varphi_{i}\right\rangle$
> be a single particle state for fermions or bosons and assume that
> there are $M$ such states, i.e.
> $|\varphi_{1}\rangle, |\varphi_{2}\rangle
>  ,\ldots,|\varphi_{M}\rangle,$ where $M$ is in general
> infinite. If the particles are fermions
> $\left|\varphi_{i}\right\rangle$ can accommodate either zero or one
> particles: this constitutes Pauli exclusion principle. If the
> particles are bosons $\left|\varphi_{i}\right\rangle$ can accommodate
> any number of them (from zero to infinity). A possible $N$-particle
> state $|\Psi\rangle$ is then a state, in which there are $n_{1}$
> identical particles in $\left|\varphi_{1}\right\rangle, n_{2}$ in
> $\left|\varphi_{2}\right\rangle,$ and so on up to $n_{M}$ in
> $\left|\varphi_{M}\right\rangle .$ The numbers $n_{i}$ are called
> occupation numbers $\left(\sum_{i=1, M} n_{i}=N\right) .$ For fermions
> the possible occupation numbers are $n_{i}=0,1,$ for bosons the
> possible occupation numbers are $n_{i}=0,1,2, \ldots, \infty .$ since
> the particles are indistinguishable we can use occupation numbers to
> label an $N$-particle state, i.e.: $$ |\Psi\rangle=\left|n_{1},
> > n_{2}, \ldots, n_{M}\right\rangle $$

So we are going over quantum ensembles. I see that in quantum systems, unlike classical systems, the wavefunction $\Psi(r_1,r_2,...,r_N)$ contains all the information in of our system - it defines out state. For a system of $N$ particles, we say that a certain state of those $N$ particles is given by $|\Psi \rangle$.

Now in this particular paragraph, we see that if I have a system of $N$ particles (they could be bosons or fermions), and we say we have $M$ states of them, and we denote them by $|\phi_k\rangle$ where $k$ goes from $1$ to $M$. My question is, what information exists in these $| \phi _k \rangle$? We say that these particles could be in states numbered from $1$ to $M$, but what do these states looks like?

From the final line, I see that $| \Psi \rangle \neq \sum_k | \phi _k \rangle$.

Which makes me wonder, what is the connection between between these states $| \phi _k \rangle$ and $|\Psi \rangle$? What are these states, and what do you attribute to them?

Comment: Please type out the relevant portion of text rather than posting an image. Images are not accessible to all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is being general because there are many ways to specify states, and some of them depend on the Hamiltonian of the system.

For example, one could have many particles in an infinite well or the Harmonic oscillator, and one could label states as the energy eigenstates. You could just be looking at spins, and so you have a number of states equal to the number of possible spin states. Or you could consider both, like with electrons in atoms. There are also cases where you can have a continuum of states. The text is just covering everything by being general.

The final part you are asking about is saying how the state vector that describes the total system is not described by a linear superposition of single particle states. It is instead described by a *product* of single particle states (or really a superposition of product states).